"'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error even with npx
'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file is about common problem: the installing of the npm package to the project does not mean the installing of it to PC, thus the OS don't know where to find the command. Here, the global installation and usage of npx are standard solutions.
But I still got:
'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

when I tried to run ts-node via npx.
As you see in the picture below, npx ncu works well:

I have not run the cowsay utility previously, so if I run npx cowsay wow, I will be prompted about installation:

Now, run npx ts-node test.ts. As you see, npx neither suggested my install it nor executed the existing file text.ts:

(My Windows 10 is Japanese, so the console output is Japanese too. That output means "'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".)

npm i ts-node if not installed already

@AbderrahmaneFatimi the OP's point is that npx is supposed to do that.

@jonrsharpe "supposed" apparently its not doing it so just install it with npm install -g globally  its not a big deal

@AbderrahmaneFatimi Thank you for the comment. "npm i ts-node if not installed already" - I am sorry, but I have not understood why I need to to this with npx. Why npx does not suggest me to install it as in case with cowsay?

This can happen if node_modules/ has been corrupted in some way. For example, on Linux:
$ rm node_modules/.bin/ts-node # delete node_modules/.bin/ts-node file
$ npx ts-node
sh: line 1: ts-node: command not found

To fix this, manually uninstall ts-node (or delete node_modules/) and then install it again.
What's going on here?
When you run npx EXECUTABLE, npx does the following things:

Looks up EXECUTABLE in a package database and finds its containing package, PACKAGE
Checks if PACKAGE is installed. If PACKAGE is not installed, it prompts for installation first
Executes node_modules/.bin/EXECUTABLE

If you install ts-node, then corrupt your node_modules/ folder, then npx still believes you have ts-node installed, so it goes to step 3 and tries running a file that no longer exists.
This is easily fixable by simply removing and installing ts-node.
